# Gradle ignores google maven repository and only searches on jcenter

Tags: android, gradle, repository

I have the following on my top-level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()

    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
}
```

I know that `google()` and `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` should point to the same place, but I decided to add both as I really need Gradle to look for packages there.

On my module `build.gradle` I have the following:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()

    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    maven { url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo' }
  }
}
```

The error message I am getting is this one:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':data:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':data:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/1.0.0/common-1.0.0.jar
```

Clearly `common-1.0.0.jar` is not present on `jcenter`. But it can be found on google maven:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/core/common/1.0.0/common-1.0.0.jar

Why is Gradle not looking there? And how can I point Gradle to the correct repository?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Nativescript are you using?

downgrading mine to 3.4.2 solved the problem for me.

```
npm uninstall -g tns
npm install -g nativescript@3.4.2
npm run clean
npm start
```

I hope this helps you. I was stuck on this for days. I tried inserting maven {...} to any app.gradle or build.gradle I could find. Finally, this is what did it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw many people having a similar issue because of nativescript. I will try your solution later.